# How to create User Dialog box while processing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to create the dialog window to ask user to click on the button when validation is successful after clicking which the new tab will open up for them to proceed further without being blocked by any popup blocker else need to show message alert.

So far I can only replace window location with URL on success.

Here is my JS file

```
$(document).ready ( function() {

    $('.promoCode').click(function() {

        // Store values in variables
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var name = form.find('input[name=name]');
        var id = form.find('input[name=id]');
        var submitted = form.find('input[name=submitted]');
        var visitor = form.find('input[name=visitor]');

        // Organize data
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&id=' + id.val() + '&submitted=' + submitted.val() + '&visitor=' + visitor.val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/_db_get_promo_code.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                if (html) {
                    window.location.replace(decodeURIComponent(html),"_blank").focus();
                } else {
                    form.find('.error').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Your Coupon Code is not valid");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I have got some info from jQuery UI page but since I am not a huge pro of programming with js I can hardly make sense out of all I have.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain. Do you want a dialog, a new tab, a popup, or just another page to load?

Comment: basically, on the page when code is entered and button is clicked, if validation was a success then dialog box should appear which will have a Thank you message and button "Purchase" after clicking on which user will have a new tab with new page link to which is going to be under Purchase now button, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For your dialog, take a look at [the docs at jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Then, to make your button open a new tab, do something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com" target="_blank"><button id="purchaseButton">Purchase</button></a>
```

And, of course, style your button to be whatever you want using `#purchaseButton`.